# MySQL return rows referencing to the same table

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table looking something like this:

```
+----+--------------+-------+----------------+------------+
| id | product_name | price | bulk_reference | bulk_count |
+----+--------------+-------+----------------+------------+
| 1  | xxxx         | 11.99 | 0              | 0          |
+----+--------------+-------+----------------+------------+
| 2  | zzzz         | 22.99 | 0              | 0          |
+----+--------------+-------+----------------+------------+
| 3  |              |       | 2              | 10         |
+----+--------------+-------+----------------+------------+
```

I can select all the  products etc, no problem. However - what I need to do is returning all the products, but lines `WHERE bulk_reference > 0` need to return the referenced  row values for `product_name` & `price` that are unset in the row... In the same result set.

So for example my result set should look something like this:

```
[0] => [id] = 1
       [product_name] = xxxx
       [price] = 11.99
       [bulk_reference] = 0
       [bulk_count] = 0

[1] => [id] = 2
       [product_name] = zzzz
       [price] = 22.99
       [bulk_reference] = 0
       [bulk_count] = 0

[2] => [id] = 3
       [product_name] = zzzz
       [price] = 22.99
       [bulk_reference] = 2
       [bulk_count] = 10
```

How can I do this with MySQL only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be fine in your case:

```
select
    P1.id,
    IF(bulk_reference>0,(select product_name from Products P2 where P2.id=P1.bulk_reference),P1.product_name) as product_name,
    IF(bulk_reference>0,(select price from Products P2 where P2.id=P1.bulk_reference), P1.price) as price,
    P1.bulk_reference,
    P1.bulk_count
from Products P1;
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/346a4/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. I do not have the possibilty right now to check the syntax, but if you get problems running it i will look into later.

```
select id , 
      (if bulk_reference > 0 then (select p1.product_name from product p1 where p1.id = p3.bulk_reference)  else product_name end if) ,
      (if bulk_reference > 0 then (select p2.price from product p2 where p2.id = p3.bulk_reference) else price end if) , 
       bulk_reference, 
       bulk_count 
from products p3
```

Comment: Ignoring your syntax, but still it's not supposed to work because the `product_name` and `price` inside the sub-query will point to the values in the same row and thus they will get the empty or null values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE bulk_reference = 0

UNION

SELECT t1.id, t2.product_name, t2.price, t1.bulk_reference, t1.bulk_count 
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t2.id = t1.bulk_reference
```